# Issue with comparing pointers to integers and making integers without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault

I am new to the C domain I am encountering a ton of warning when compiling involving comparing pointers to integers and making an integer from a pointer without a cast.  Could you point me in a direction to help fix this? I have attached my code and a sample file.  Once compile in order to run as arguments you need to include the input file name followed by the output file name you prefer.  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUF_LEN 1024


int SendOut(char *SywUserIdTemp, char *IntractnIdBuf1, char *IntractnIdBuf2, char *IntractnIdBuf3, 
                    char *DivNbrBuf1, char *DivNbrBuf2, char *DivNbrBuf3, 
                    char *ItemNbrBuf1, char *ItemNbrBuf2, char *ItemNbrBuf3, 
                    char *KsnIdBuf1, char *KsnIdBuf2, char *KsnIdBuf3,
                    char *buddy_cntBuf1, char *buddy_cntBuf2, char *buddy_cntBuf3,
                    int today_month, int all, int n1, int n2, int n3, char *summer_active_temp, char *winter_active_temp, FILE *fpOut)
{
    int i;
    //determine triggers
    //if no active out of season and season is winter
    if(summer_active_temp == '0' && today_month == '1')
    {
        //if enough of winter to do 60% winter 40% non seasonal
        if(n3 >= 12)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) //nonseasonal
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n3; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (20-n3))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (20-n3); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //if active out of season and season is winter
    else if(summer_active_temp == '1' && today_month == '1')
    {
        //if enough do 25% summer 50% winter 25% nonseasonal
        if(n3 >= 10 && n2 >= 5)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= 5)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(n3 >= 10 && n2 < 5)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n2; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (10-n2))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (10-n2); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(n3 < 10 && n2 >= 5)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n3; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (15-n3))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (15-n3); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n2; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n3; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (20-n3-n2))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (20-n3-n2); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //if no active out of season and season is summer
    else if(winter_active_temp == '0' && today_month == '2')
    {
        //if enough of summer to do 60% summer 40% non seasonal
        if(n2 >= 12)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= 8)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n2; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (20-n2))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (20-n2); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //if active out of season and season is summer
    else if(winter_active_temp == '1' && today_month == '2')
    {
        //if enough do 25% winter 50% summer 25% nonseasonal
        if(n2 >= 10 && n3 >= 5)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= 5)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(n2 >= 10 && n3 < 5)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n3; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (10-n3))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (10-n3); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(n2 < 10 && n3 >= 5)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n2; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (15-n2))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (15-n2); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n3; ++i) //winter
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n2; ++i) //summer
            {
                fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,2\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf2[i], DivNbrBuf2[i], ItemNbrBuf2[i], KsnIdBuf2[i], buddy_cntBuf2[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
            }

            //just in case nonseasonal doesnt have enough to fill in
            if(n1 >= (20-n3-n2))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < (20-n3-n2); ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) //nonseasonal
                {
                    fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,1\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1[i], DivNbrBuf1[i], ItemNbrBuf1[i], KsnIdBuf1[i], buddy_cntBuf1[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return(0);
}

int main(int argn, char* argv[])
{
    //initialize variables
    int i, all;
    //char SywUserId, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, cnt_rank, table_type, summer_active, summer_active_temp, winter_active, winter_active_temp, SywUserIdTemp;
    char *SywUserId, *IntractnId, *DivNbr, *ItemNbr, *KsnId, *buddy_cnt, *cnt_rank, *table_type, *summer_active, *winter_active, *summer_active_temp, *winter_active_temp, *SywUserIdTemp;
    FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    char IntractnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN], DivNbrBuf1[BUF_LEN], ItemNbrBuf1[BUF_LEN], KsnIdBuf1[BUF_LEN], buddy_cntBuf1[BUF_LEN];
    char IntractnIdBuf2[BUF_LEN], DivNbrBuf2[BUF_LEN], ItemNbrBuf2[BUF_LEN], KsnIdBuf2[BUF_LEN], buddy_cntBuf2[BUF_LEN];
    char IntractnIdBuf3[BUF_LEN], DivNbrBuf3[BUF_LEN], ItemNbrBuf3[BUF_LEN], KsnIdBuf3[BUF_LEN], buddy_cntBuf3[BUF_LEN];
    int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0;
    int nRow=0, iCount=0;

    //determine season
    int today_month = 0;
    time_t result = time(NULL);
    struct tm* today = (localtime(&result));
    char month_str[3];
    strftime(month_str, sizeof(month_str), "%m", today);
    if(*month_str < "03" || *month_str > "08"){
        today_month = 1; //winter
    }
    else{
        today_month = 2; //summer
    }

    //if input does not have 3 arguments terminate
    if(argn != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        return(-1);
    }

    //check for input file
    fpIn = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fpIn == NULL) {
        printf("Error: no input file");
    }

    //check for output files
    fpOut = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(fpOut == NULL) {
        printf("Error: no output file");
    }
    // Skip the first row.
    //fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, fpIn); 
    // Process the data.
    fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, fpIn);
    SywUserIdTemp = '0';
    winter_active_temp = '0';
    summer_active_temp = '0';
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 0;
    n3 = 0;
    all = 0;
    while(!feof(fpIn)) {
        if(strlen(buf) < 2) break;
        // Remove CR or LF at the tail.
        i=strlen(buf)-1; while(i > 0 && buf[i] <= ' ') buf[i--] = '\0';
        SywUserId = strtok(buf, ",");
        table_type = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cnt_rank = strtok(NULL, ",");
        IntractnId = strtok(NULL, ",");
        DivNbr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        ItemNbr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        KsnId = strtok(NULL, ",");
        buddy_cnt = strtok(NULL, ",");
        summer_active = strtok(NULL, ",");
        winter_active = strtok(NULL, ",");
        printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", SywUserId, table_type, cnt_rank, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, summer_active, winter_active);

        //if it is the same member the ksn number is saved in a buffer to create pairs from
        if(SywUserIdTemp == SywUserId)
        {
            if(table_type == 1)
            {
                IntractnIdBuf1[n1] = IntractnId;
                DivNbrBuf1[n1] = DivNbr;
                ItemNbrBuf1[n1] = ItemNbr;
                KsnIdBuf1[n1] = KsnId;
                buddy_cntBuf1[n1++] = buddy_cnt;
            }
            else if(table_type == 2)
            {
                IntractnIdBuf2[n2] = IntractnId;
                DivNbrBuf2[n2] = DivNbr;
                ItemNbrBuf2[n2] = ItemNbr;
                KsnIdBuf2[n2] = KsnId;
                buddy_cntBuf2[n2++] = buddy_cnt;
            }
            else //table_type == 3
            {
                IntractnIdBuf3[n3] = IntractnId;
                DivNbrBuf3[n3] = DivNbr;
                ItemNbrBuf3[n3] = ItemNbr;
                KsnIdBuf3[n3] = KsnId;
                buddy_cntBuf3[n3++] = buddy_cnt;
            }

            all++;
        }
        //else all the combos are created and written to the output file
        //the new mbrId is copied to the tempMbrId
        //the nKsn is reset to 0 and the new ksnId is saved in the buffer
        else
        {
            if(SywUserIdTemp != 0)
            {
                SendOut(SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1, IntractnIdBuf2, IntractnIdBuf3, 
                    DivNbrBuf1, DivNbrBuf2, DivNbrBuf3, 
                    ItemNbrBuf1, ItemNbrBuf2, ItemNbrBuf3, 
                    KsnIdBuf1, KsnIdBuf2, KsnIdBuf3,
                    buddy_cntBuf1, buddy_cntBuf2, buddy_cntBuf3,
                    today_month, all, n1, n2, n3, summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp, fpOut);
            }
            //reset info
            SywUserIdTemp = SywUserId;
            summer_active_temp = summer_active;
            winter_active_temp = winter_active;
            n1 = 0;
            n2 = 0;
            n3 = 0;
            all = 0;
            if(table_type == 1)
            {
                IntractnIdBuf1[n1] = IntractnId;
                DivNbrBuf1[n1] = DivNbr;
                ItemNbrBuf1[n1] = ItemNbr;
                KsnIdBuf1[n1] = KsnId;
                buddy_cntBuf1[n1++] = buddy_cnt;
            }
            else if(table_type == 2)
            {
                IntractnIdBuf2[n2] = IntractnId;
                DivNbrBuf2[n2] = DivNbr;
                ItemNbrBuf2[n2] = ItemNbr;
                KsnIdBuf2[n2] = KsnId;
                buddy_cntBuf2[n2++] = buddy_cnt;
            }
            else //table_type == 3
            {
                IntractnIdBuf3[n3] = IntractnId;
                DivNbrBuf3[n3] = DivNbr;
                ItemNbrBuf3[n3] = ItemNbr;
                KsnIdBuf3[n3] = KsnId;
                buddy_cntBuf3[n3++] = buddy_cnt;
            }

            all++;
            //printf("nKsn=%d", nKsn);
        }
        // Show the progress.
        nRow++;
        if( iCount < 999 ) {
            iCount++;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", nRow);
            iCount = 0;
        }
        fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, fpIn);
    }
    SendOut(SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf1, IntractnIdBuf2, IntractnIdBuf3, 
                    DivNbrBuf1, DivNbrBuf2, DivNbrBuf3, 
                    ItemNbrBuf1, ItemNbrBuf2, ItemNbrBuf3, 
                    KsnIdBuf1, KsnIdBuf2, KsnIdBuf3,
                    buddy_cntBuf1, buddy_cntBuf2, buddy_cntBuf3,
                    today_month, all, n1, n2, n3, summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp, fpOut);

    //close files when done
    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);

    //exit program
    return(0);
}
```

test_data.txt

```
1,1,1,-276551,7,63062,0,1.993,0,0,
1,1,10,24315147,54,41796,0,1.934,0,0,
1,1,11,25562371,2,40396,3747849,1.934,0,0,
1,1,12,-948793,2,2820,0,1.919,0,0,
1,1,13,4272725,44,20243,0,1.911,0,0,
1,1,14,2917566,44,71641,0,1.900,0,0,
1,1,15,24655338,54,71593,0,1.898,0,0,
1,1,16,22365342,44,67862,0,1.894,0,0,
1,1,17,12690269,44,14216,0,1.886,0,0,
1,1,18,2920093,44,93074,0,1.875,0,0,
1,1,19,8569801,2,40396,0,1.868,0,0,
1,1,2,-273684,7,63204,0,1.984,0,0,
1,1,20,10171246,88,2379,0,1.859,0,0,
1,1,3,1617035,44,72854,0,1.977,0,0,
1,1,4,12690127,44,14602,0,1.973,0,0,
1,1,5,13064870,44,13666,0,1.966,0,0,
1,1,6,1616493,44,34869,0,1.966,0,0,
1,1,7,1617032,44,72854,0,1.956,0,0,
1,1,8,1616460,44,23337,0,1.950,0,0,
1,1,9,24655107,2,94350,0,1.948,0,0,
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here.  Can you create a much smaller example program which generates the same warnings and post it instead please?

Comment: I had subsets of the code that work fine, it was when I inserted them into the larger section that I had all the problems.  Im sorry for the vast amount of code.  The whole beginning function doesnt really have problems its the main function.

Comment: I see a lot of similar code that is repeated (The code done inside the `if`s in `SendOut`. That's a hint for you to make a function out of it and avoid copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out your pointers as integers. The correct format specifier for pointers is `"%p"`, not `"%lu"`.

Comment: Reading the data in from the file and printing it out in that manner works fine in a separate file.  I think I am just not clear on what in my code is acting as pointers and how to deal with that.  My code background is mostly java based.

Comment: `fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);` prints a lot of stuff. `SywUserIdTemp` is a pointer type, but you print it as `unsigned long`. The correct specifier would be `%p` for pointer type.

Comment: I realized I forgot to change all the prints to print %s instead of %lu when I changed my initial variable type earlier today.  Can you explain why it is a pointer type instead of a string?  Also, can I make it just act as a string?

Comment: @Babs C has no string type. In C a "string" is a pointer to the first character of the string and it ends with a `'\0'` null terminator. Thus the correct type for "strings" in C is `char *`. You give it meaning as a "string" by specifying the `"%s"` format specifier that instructs `printf` to print as many characters starting from that pointer until `'\0'` is encountered.

Comment: So in the printf statement would the %s and %p be interchangeable?  Is it better practice to use a certain one?

Comment: @Babs They will produce different output. `"%s"` would print a string. `"%p"` will print the numerical value of that pointer (the VM address it points to).

Comment: When I am referring to the variables throughout the code how would I write the variable to refer to the string value in comparison to just having the numerical value of the point?

Comment: @Babs It depends on what you do with it. If you are only passing it around then the proper type is `char *` which is a numeric pointer. If you cant to access the characters then you can do this in the normal array notation `my_string[i]`. The pointer is given meaning as a string by the function that consumes it.

Comment: So, I get an error on the following code saying that my assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast: IntractnIdBuf3[n3] = IntractnId;.  What would be the proper way to set this slot in the buffer equal to the full value of IntractnId which is initialized as char *IntractnId and the value is set with the following code: IntractnId = strtok(NULL, ","); ?

Comment: @Babs I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do there, but if your intention is to copy the string then the proper way is to use `strcpy`: `strncpy(IntractnIdBuf3, IntractnId, BUF_LEN - 1);`

Comment: n3 is the current index in the buffer that the string value would need to be copied into.  For instance if the string contained the id of "A23829" I would like that entire value to be in that space in the buffer.  Is there a way to specify the index of the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(fpOut, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,%lu,3\n", SywUserIdTemp, IntractnIdBuf3[i], DivNbrBuf3[i], ItemNbrBuf3[i], KsnIdBuf3[i], buddy_cntBuf3[i], summer_active_temp, winter_active_temp);
```

The %lu says that SywUserIdTemp should be a an integer, but you passed it a C string, a char pointer. You want to use %s instead of 5lu for that parameter, assuming that it's a NUL terminated C string.

Comment: Oh. I completely forgot to change those over when I altered my initial variables to be strings instead of longs.

Comment: With that fix I still get warnings for assignment makes integer from pointer without a case in the line ranges from around 350 to 480.

Answer (score 0):

This line

> if(*month_str < "03" || *month_str > "08"){

has three problems:

1. the expression `*month_str` gives you the first *character* in `month_str`, and the type of the expression is `char`, not `char *`.  That's the source of at least one of your "comparison of pointer to integer" errors, because...
2. In this context, the string literals `"03"` and `"08"` will ultimately have the type `char *`, and will evaluate to the address of the first element of each string, but the bigger issue is...
3. You cannot compare string values using the relational operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, etc.).  You must use the `strcmp` library function instead.

That line should be

```
if ( strcmp( month_str, "03" ) < 0 || strcmp( month_str, "08" ) > 0 )
{
   ...
}
```

Check your handy C reference manual for an explanation of `strcmp`'s return value.

Comment: So, I updated throughout my code with this method and with a few at the top I have the following issue.  Here is an example of the code:     if( strcmp( summer_active_temp, "0" ) == 0 && strcmp( today_month, "1" ) == 0).  I get the following error:  warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcmpâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @Babs: that's because you declared `today_month` as an integer, not a pointer to `char`.  So the statement should be `if (strcmp( summer_active_temp, "0") == 0 && today_month == 1 )`.  You *really* need to sit down with a good C reference and learn about the different types and the operations allowed on those types, because you're confusing pointers with integers with individual characters all over the place.

Comment: Do you have an recommendations for a C reference I can study?

Comment: @Babs: My go-to reference has been Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/) since the mid-1980's.  Kernighan & Ritchie's [The C Programming Language](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628), while very old, is still one of the better introductions to the language; just be aware it's a bit out of date, and doesn't cover any of the changes made to the language since 1999.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation and your help.  I appreciate it greatly!